# Comparing std::tuple (or std::pair) of custom types who has alternative orderings. Is it possible to plug-in a custom less-than / comparison function?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std-pair, stdtuple

## The Problem

I have a custom type `A` who has natural ordering (having `operator<`) and multiple alternative orderings (case-sensitive, case-insensitive, etc.). Now I have a `std::pair` (or `std::tuple`) consisting (one or more of) `A`. Here are some examples of types I want to compare: `std::pair<A, int>`, `std::pair<int, A>`, `std::tuple<A, int, int>`, `std::tuple<int, A, int>`. How can I compare the `std::pair` (or `std::tuple`) using the default element-wise comparison implementation, plugging-in my comparison function for `A`?

## The Code

The code below doesn't compile:

```
#include <utility>      // std::pair
#include <tuple>        // std::tuple
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl

struct A
{
    A(char v) : value(v) {}
    char value;
};

// LOCATION-1 (explained in the text below)

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << "Testing std::pair of primitive types: "
        << (std::pair<char, int>('A', 1)
                <
            std::pair<char, int>('a', 0))
        << std::endl;

    std::cout
        << "Testing std::tuple of primitive types: "
        << (std::tuple<char, int, double>('A', 1, 1.0)
                <
            std::tuple<char, int, double>('a', 0, 0.0))
        << std::endl;

    // This doesn't compile:
    std::cout
        << "Testing std::pair of custom types: "
        << (std::pair<A, int>('A', 1)
                <
            std::pair<A, int>('a', 0))
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is because `operator<` isn't defined for `struct A`. Adding it to `LOCATION-1` above would solve the problem:

```
bool operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}
```

Now, we have an alternative ordering for `struct A`:

```
bool case_insensitive_less_than(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)
{
    char const lhs_value_case_insensitive
        = ('a' <= lhs.value && lhs.value <= 'z'
            ? (lhs.value + 0x20)
            : lhs.value);
    char const rhs_value_case_insensitive
        = ('a' <= rhs.value && rhs.value <= 'z'
            ? (rhs.value + 0x20)
            : rhs.value);
    return lhs_value_case_insensitive < rhs_value_case_insensitive;
}
```

Supposed we want to keep the original `operator<` for `struct A` (the case-sensitive one), how can we compare `std::pair<A, int>` with this alternative ordering?

I know that adding a specialized version of `operator<` for `std::pair<A, int>` solves the problem:

```
bool operator<(std::pair<A, int> const& lhs, std::pair<A, int> const& rhs)
{
    return (case_insensitive_less_than(lhs.first, rhs.first)
        ? true
        : case_insensitive_less_than(rhs.first, lhs.first)
        ? false
        : (lhs.second < rhs.second));
}
```

However, I consider this a sub-optimal solution.

Firstly, for `std::pair`, it is easy to re-implement the element-wise comparison, but for `std::tuple` it might be complicated (dealing with variadic templates) and error-prone.

Secondly, I can hardly believe that it is the best-practice way to solve the problem: imagine that we have to define a specialized version of `operator<` for each of the following classes: `std::tuple<A, int, int>`, `std::tuple<int, A, int>`, `std::tuple<int, int, A>`, `std::tuple<A, A, int>`, ... (It's not even a practical way!)

Re-using the well written built-in `operator<` for `std::tuple` and plugging-in my `less-than` for `struct A` would be what I want. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's relatively straightforward to write a custom comparison function that does what you want. Do you really want the `<` syntax?

Comment: Well, the function is not required to be named `operator<` for `std::pair<A, int>` (or `std::tuple<A, int, int>`), another names may be used, as far as the `std::pair` (or `std::tuple`) could be used as the key of a `std::map`, using the constructor that accepts a comparison function as parameter. But I don't want to write (all manually) one `less-than` function for `std::tuple<A, int, int>` and another `less-than` function for `std::tuple<int, A, int>` and so on. I would like to reuse the default `less-than` for `std::pair` (or `std::tuple`) as I mentioned in my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to manually write `compare( tup, tup, f )` that uses `f` to lexographically compare the elements in the tuples.  But that is boring.

```
// This type wraps a reference of type X&&
// it then overrides == and < with L and E respectively
template<class X, class L, class E>
struct reorder_ref {
  using ref = reorder_ref;
  X&& x;
  friend bool operator<(ref lhs, ref rhs) {
    return L{}((X&&) lhs.x, (X&&) rhs.x);
  }
  friend bool operator==(ref lhs, ref rhs) {
    return E{}((X&&) lhs.x, (X&&) rhs.x);
  }
  // other comparison ops based off `==` and `<` go here
  friend bool operator!=(ref lhs, ref rhs){return !(lhs==rhs);}
  friend bool operator>(ref lhs, ref rhs){return rhs<lhs;}
  friend bool operator<=(ref lhs, ref rhs){return !(lhs>rhs);}
  friend bool operator>=(ref lhs, ref rhs){return !(lhs<rhs);}

  reorder_ref(X&& x_) : x((X&&) x_) {}
  reorder_ref(reorder_ref const&) = default;
};
```

the above is a reference that changes how we order.

```
// a type tag, to pass a type to a function:
template<class X>class tag{using type=X;};

// This type takes a less than and equals stateless functors
// and takes as input a tuple, and builds a tuple of reorder_refs
// basically it uses L and E to compare the elements, but otherwise
// uses std::tuple's lexographic comparison code.
template<class L, class E>
struct reorder_tuple {
  // indexes trick:
  template<class Tuple, class R, size_t... Is>
  R operator()(tag<R>, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple const& in) const {
    // use indexes trick to do conversion
    return R( std::get<Is>(in)... );
  }

  // forward to the indexes trick above:
  template<class... Ts, class R=std::tuple<reorder_ref<Ts const&, L, E>...>>
  R operator()(std::tuple<Ts...> const& in) const {
    return (*this)(tag<R>{}, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, in);
  }
  // pair filter:
  template<class... Ts, class R=std::pair<reorder_ref<Ts const&, L, E>...>>
  R operator()(std::pair<Ts...> const& in) const {
    return (*this)(tag<R>{}, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, in);
  }
};
```

the above stateless function object takes some new less and equals operations, and maps any tuple to a tuple of `reorder_ref<const T, ...>`, which change the ordering to follow `L` and `E` respectively.

This next type does what `std::less<void>` does for `std::less<T>` sort of -- it takes a type-specific stateless ordering function template object, and makes it a type-generic stateless ordering function object:

```
// This takes a type-specific ordering stateless function type, and turns
// it into a generic ordering function type
template<template<class...> class order>
struct generic_order {
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) const {
    return order<T>{}(lhs, rhs);
  }
};
```

so if we have a `template<class T>class Z` such that `Z<T>` is an ordering on `T`s, the above gives you a universal ordering on anything.

This next one is a favorite of mine.  It takes a type T, and orders it based on a mapping to a type U.  This is surprisingly useful:

```
// Suppose there is a type X for which we have an ordering L
// and we have a map O from Y->X.  This builds an ordering on
// (Y lhs, Y rhs) -> L( O(lhs), O(rhs) ).  We "order" our type
// "by" the projection of our type into another type.  For
// a concrete example, imagine we have an "id" structure with a name
// and age field.  We can write a function "return s.age;" to
// map our id type into ints (age).  If we order by that map,
// then we order the "id" by age.
template<class O, class L = std::less<>>
struct order_by {
  template<class T, class U>
  bool operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const {
    return L{}( O{}((T&&) t), O{}((U&&) u) );
  }
};
```

Now we glue it all together:

```
// Here is where we build a special order.  Suppose we have a template Z<X> that returns
// a stateless order on type X.  This takes that ordering, and builds an ordering on
// tuples based on it, using the above code as glue:
template<template<class...>class Less, template<class...>class Equals=std::equal_to>
using tuple_order = order_by< reorder_tuple< generic_order<Less>, generic_order<Equals> > >;
```

`tuple_order` does most of the work for us.  All we need is to provide it with an element-wise ordering `template` stateless function object.  `tuple_order` will then produce a tuple ordering functor based on it.

```
// Here is a concrete use of the above
// my_less is a sorting functiont that sorts everything else the usual way
// but it sorts Foo's backwards
// Here is a toy type.  It wraps an int.  By default, it sorts in the usual way
struct Foo {
  int value = 0;
  // usual sort:
  friend bool operator<( Foo lhs, Foo rhs ) {
    return lhs.value<rhs.value;
  }
  friend bool operator==( Foo lhs, Foo rhs ) {
    return lhs.value==rhs.value;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct my_less : std::less<T> {};

// backwards sort:
template<>
struct my_less<Foo> {
  bool operator()(Foo const& lhs, Foo const& rhs) const {
    return rhs.value < lhs.value;
  }
};

using special_order = tuple_order< my_less >;
```

[and bob is your uncle (live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/794f8a62db4c10de).

`special_order` can be passed to a `std::map` or `std::set`, and it will order any tuples or pairs encountered with `my_less` replacing the default ordering of the elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's really cool! I think I have to take some time to digest (and then accept) your solution. As far as I can see, `typename X` is the type going to be compared, `typename L` seems to be the `less-than` functor, and `typename E` seems to be the `equals` functor. I'm still digesting other parts. I'm afraid you made a typo in `operator==` (you wrote `operator=-`).

Comment: @siu if that is the only typo, consider yourself lucky!  The idea is to project element-wise less onto a tuple's less code (the reorder ref part maps a tuple to a tuple that uses a different element wise less), then use that projection to order tuples (with order by, which takes an order on A and a map from B to A and produces an order on B).

Comment: Wow! That sounds complicated! Do you mean: **1.** I have to write the comparison function for `std::tuple<A, int, char>` manually. **2.** Your code automatically maps `std::tuple<int, A, char>`, `std::tuple<int, char, A>` (etc) to `std::tuple<A, int, char>` for comparison? Will it compare the elements in the declared order then? Will it work for `std::tuple<A, int, A>` too? Sorry that I'm still figuring out how your code works. Thanks!

Comment: @siu no.  Reorder (if you finish it -- there is a big todo there) takes an element-wise comparison, and maps tuples to tuples ordered by that element-wise comparison.  It takes `tuple<Foo,int>` to `tuple<reorder_ref<Foo>,reorder_ref<int>>` roughly (more `const&`s and `my_less` types etc in reality).  `<` on the output tuple does the right thing.  order_by uses that to order any tuple directly.

Comment: Now, I'm reading the code backwards. `no_case` is the functor that acts as `operator<` in the map. `no_case` is equivalent to `order_by<reorder_t<my_less, my_equals>>` (you wrote `reorder` instead of `reorder_t`, but I guess it's a typo). `order_by<O, L>` accepts 2 template parameters (one being optional). It can compare any `T` and `U` by calling `L` on `T` and `U` casted to `O`. Now, `O` refers to `reorder_t<my_less, my_equals>`, and `L` refers to `std::less<>`. I guess `reorder_t` is the "big TODO" you were referring to. I can't see how it works. Could you please add more explanations?

Comment: I can see that `my_less<T>` is a template class. It is a functor. It relies on template specialization to do the trick. For any type without a specialization, it acts the same as `std::less<T>`. For any type with a specialization, it calls the specialized version. So, my `bool case_insensitive_less_than(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)` is the same as your `my_less<Foo>::operator()(Foo const&, Foo const&)` here. But I have no idea what `helper` does here, and how it works. It doesn't even show up in the later code! So, could you explain more on that? Thanks!

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- ok, edited, typos fixed, some types renamed to better names, comments added, and live example linked.